# Conditional Fields on HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

I hope you can help me on this one.

This code below is supposed to show a number of field if people select more than 0 and up to 3.

But nothing is happening when selecting 1 2 or 3. Could you have a look and let me know how can i fix?

Thanks

```html
<select name="children" id="childOccupants">
    <option value="0" selected>0</option>
    <?php 
        for ($j = 1; $j <= 3; $j++) { 
            echo "<option value='$j'>$j</option>"; 

        } 
    ?>
</select>

<!-- Dynamic children boxes -->
<span id='childAges'>
    <script>
        $("#childOccupants").bind('change', function () {
            $("#childAges").empty();
            var children = $("#childOccupants").val();
            var s = 1;
            for (i=0; i < children; i++) {
                $("<label for='child" + s + "'>Child " + s + " age</label><input type='text' name='child" + s + "' id='child" + s + "' />").appendTo("#childAges");
                s++;
            }
        })
    </script>
</span>
<!-- End of dynamic child age boxes -->
```

Comment: [It looks to be working](https://jsfiddle.net/vw9cxzph/1/), but it's hard to know what you're looking for.  Maybe your PHP isn't working?

Comment: Thank you for answering, the jquery link was not working. So you are right.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        $("#childOccupants").bind('change', function () {
            $("#childAges").empty();
            var children = $("#childOccupants").val();
            var s = 1;
            for (i=0; i < children; i++) {
                ("#childAges").append("<label for='child" + s + "'>Child " + s + " age</label><input type='text' name='child" + s + "' id='child" + s + "' />");
                s++;
            }
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. the JQuery was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included javascript and checked the console logs?

The below is working fine for me.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select name="children" id="childOccupants">
            <option value="0" selected>0</option>
            <?php
                for ($j = 1; $j <= 3; $j++) {
                    echo "<option value='$j'>$j</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <!-- Dynamic children boxes -->
        <span id='childAges'>
            <script>
                $("#childOccupants").bind('change', function () {
                    $("#childAges").empty();
                    var children = $("#childOccupants").val();
                    var s = 1;
                    for (i=0; i < children; i++) {
                        $("<label for='child" + s + "'>Child " + s + " age</label><input type='text' name='child" + s + "' id='child" + s + "' />").appendTo("#childAges");
                        s++;
                    }
                })
            </script>
        </span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are right, the jquery link was not working. Thank you

Comment: Please accept the answer if it works. It will be helpful for other